# /media/search/ Returning nothing with a valid access token

Tags: instagram-api

The API endpoint:

'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/searchlat=48.858844&lng=-122.418&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN'

This is returning no data when passed a valid access token.

`{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}`

I've tried it with multiple lat & lng params but it still always returns the code '200' with data being null.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/searchlat=48.858844&lng=-122.418&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

1. You're missing a `?` between `search` and `lat`.
2. Afair, Instagram is only returning a certain amount of recent items. If you still receive no results after fixing 1), you might want to try a more "popular" location
3. There's also a `distance` parameter, where you can increase the search radius (up to 5000 meters, according to the current API spec.)

Comment: The issue was that it was only returning media from sandbox users. I made a test account, added it as sandbox user, took a photo, attached a location and it worked.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I pasted the wrong URL into the question.